# EOFError - Uploading .csv file using ftplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, ftplib

Im trying to upload .csv files using ftplib on python3.
My code looks like this:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import os, sys

def get_script_path():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

script_path = get_script_path()
ftp = FTP_TLS(host='hostedftp.com')
ftp.login('USER','123456789')
ftp.prot_p() 

filename = script_path + '/Test.csv'
fp = open(filename, 'r')
ftp.storlines("STOR " + filename, fp)

ftp.close()
```

And im getting:

> File "ftp_test.py", line 15, in 
>       ftp.storlines("STOR " + filename, fp) ... File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py",
>   line 208, in getline
>       raise EOFError EOFError

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried `ftp.storbinary`? Maybe there's a non-ASCII character in your file, could we see a sample?

Comment: Yes @TomasFarias but i got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you switch to using the binary mode. This also involves opening the file with `rb`. For example:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import os, sys

def get_script_path():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

script_path = get_script_path()
ftp = FTP_TLS(host='hostedftp.com')
ftp.login('USER','123456789')
ftp.prot_p() 

filename = 'Test.csv'

with open(os.path.join(get_script_path(), filename), 'rb') as fp:
    try:
        ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, fp)
        ftp.quit()   # This can raise EOFError if the connection has closed 
    except EOFError:
        pass

ftp.close()
```

If the file has uploaded ok, you could also catch the `EOFError` which can be raised if the connection has closed.

Comment: Im getting the same error but on the ftp.quit() line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was using the full path on the STOR command. 
Here is the fixed code:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import os, sys

def get_script_path():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

script_path = get_script_path()

ftp = FTP_TLS(host='hostedftp.com')
ftp.login('USER','123456789')
ftp.prot_p() 
filename_path = script_path + '/Test.csv'
filename = 'Test.csv'
fp = open(filename_path, 'rb')
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, fp)
fp.close()
ftp.quit()
```

Notice how i use the `filename_path` to open it and get the `fp` but the actual `filename` for the STOR command.